# Fitting curved edges separated by sharp corners

Tags: opencv, contour, edge-detection

EDIT: To further clarify if my question is not clear,

- **Input:** The image below
- **Output:** The points on edge 1, the points on edge 2, the points on edge 3, and the points on edge 4. (I **do not** have a problem finding contours. I am just unable to separate the points that lie on each of the four edges. I want to group those points into four **separate** edges so that I can fit four separate curves to them)

My problem here is to detect points and fit **separate** curves to each of the curved edges of objects like what is shown below (The image shown is one example. The actual shape of each object is different, but there will be either a sharp corner or change in slope from one edge to another):

[image]

One way to approach this is to separate out the points/pixels on each edge (the four lines in the above example) and fit polynomials on each of them. By searching a little bit, I learnt that Hough Transform is available for detecting straight edges in OpenCV, but not for curved edges. I also tried detecting contours, but it does not separate out edges of a closed shape. The main criterion for an edge to be considered separate from an adjacent one is that there is a sharp change in slope.

Could anyone give me ideas on how to achieve this? I prefer using C++ with OpenCV due to the other modules of my task.

Comment: Do your images have noise? E.g. are there dark pixels outside the shape boundary that are dark just because of noise? Also, are your shapes convex like the one you draw?

Comment: (1) Yes. There would be noise. But I have access to a light box to eliminate background noise (thresholding based on brightness). The only noise would be internal to the shape. After thresholding, I can apply the Canny edge detection (2) The shapes are not all convex. Some are concave.

Comment: The question is hard to understand, because its not really clear what is input and what is the exact output expected. I guess what you want is along the lines of: (1) Apply bit of blur to smooth out distortions (2) Binary threshold since we just care about the borders (3) Find the largest blob using flood fill / or eg. canny if that works for you (4) findContours ...

Comment: @BjoernRennhak No. I can already get contours of the above  shape. That is not a problem. I want to parametrize the edges and hence I need the points/pixel locations on each edge. **Input:** The example image above. **Output:** points on edge 1, points on edge 2, points on edge 3, and points on edge 4

Comment: Ah, right, the image above is Input. From your question I thought its the output or sth. I think what you maybe want is `#findContours` in OpenCV. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: @Shivanand could you kindly edit your question? Its very hard to understand. If its clearer probably you will get your answer quicker. Thank you.

Comment: @BjoernRennhak (1) Okay. I will edit the question. (2)  I am already familiar with finding contours. I can already do that. Finding contours is not my problem at all. It is easy. I wanted to separate each edge from a closed shape. Finding contours gives me the whole shape as one contour. I wanted to detect each edge as a separate entity so that I can fit a different curve on each edge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172018/discussion-between-shivanand-and-bjoern-rennhak).

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is essentially to find high curvature points in the outline. There are several methods for curvature estimation. Some are based on local derivatives of the intensity, and some are based on the arrangement of the pixels along the curve. This problem is very close to that of corner detection.

You may be interested by the following references: "A Comparative Study
on 2D Curvature Estimators, Simon Hermann and Reinhard Klette" or "Curvature estimation in noisy curves, Thanh Phuong Nguyen, Isabelle Debled-Rennesson". Notice that there is large litterature on the topic as curvature estimation in the digital domain is uneasy because it takes second order derivatives.

Comment: Is there an implementation of this (preferably in OpenCV, C++) that I could use? This task is really a small part of what I am doing, and coding it in C++ might take me a while.

Comment: @Shivanand: life is life.

Comment: @Shivanand very doubtful, unfortunately. Not a trivial task.